# Related Field got invalid lookup: title_icontains

Tags: python, django, class, view, django-views

My model.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, post_save
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.text import slugify

# Create your models here.
class Stocks(models.Model):

    title = models.ForeignKey('Product', verbose_name="Ürün", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stock = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3,decimal_places=0,default=0,verbose_name="Stok")
    seller = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100,decimal_places=2,default=0.00,verbose_name="Fiyat")    

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Stok"
        verbose_name_plural = "Stoklar"


def upload_image_location(instance, filename):
    return "%s/%s" %(instance.id, filename)

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name="Başlık")
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Kategori",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True,verbose_name="Ürün Açıklaması")
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100,decimal_places=2,default=0.00,verbose_name="Fiyat")
    sale_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100,decimal_places=2,default=0.00,null=True,blank=True,verbose_name="İndirimli Fiyat")
    tax = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3,default=18,decimal_places=0,verbose_name="KDV")
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True,verbose_name="Aktif/Pasif")
    image1 = models.FileField(blank=True,null=True,upload_to=upload_image_location,verbose_name="Vitrin Fotoğrafı")
    image2 = models.FileField(blank=True,null=True,upload_to=upload_image_location,verbose_name="Galeri Fotoğrafı 1")
    image3 = models.FileField(blank=True,null=True,upload_to=upload_image_location,verbose_name="Galeri Fotoğrafı 2")
    image4 = models.FileField(blank=True,null=True,upload_to=upload_image_location,verbose_name="Galeri Fotoğrafı 3")
    image5 = models.FileField(blank=True,null=True,upload_to=upload_image_location,verbose_name="Galeri Fotoğrafı 4")

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        view_name = "detail_slug"
        return reverse(view_name, kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Ürün'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Ürünler'

def create_slug(instance, new_slug=None):
    slug = slugify(instance.title)
    if new_slug is not None:
        slug = new_slug
    qs = Product.objects.filter(slug=slug)
    exists = qs.exists()
    if exists:
        new_slug = "%s-%s" %(slug, qs.first().id)
        return create_slug(instance, new_slug=new_slug)
    return slug

def product_pre_save_reciever(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = create_slug(instance)

pre_save.connect(product_pre_save_reciever, sender=Product)
```

My views.py

```
class ProductDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, MultiSlugMixin, DetailView):
    model = Product

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        product_name = self.object.title
        data = Stocks.objects.filter(title__icontains=product_name).order_by('price')
        context['stocks'] = data
        return context
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from products import views

from products.views import (
    CategoryCreateView,
    CategoryUpdateView,
    ProductCreateView,
    ProductListView,
    ProductDetailView,
    ProductUpdateView,

    )

urlpatterns = [

    path('urunler/', ProductListView.as_view(), name='list'),
    path('urunler/ekle/', ProductCreateView.as_view(), name='create'),
    path('urunler/duzenle/<int:pk>/', ProductUpdateView.as_view(), name='update'),
    path('urunler/duzenle/<slug>/', ProductUpdateView.as_view(), name='update_slug'),
    path('urunler/<int:pk>/', ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('urunler/<slug>/', ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='detail_slug'),
    path('kategori/ekle/', CategoryCreateView.as_view(), name='add_category'),
    path('kategori/duzenle/<int:pk>/', CategoryUpdateView.as_view(), name='update_category'),
    path('kategori/duzenle/<slug>/', CategoryUpdateView.as_view(), name='update_slug_category'),


]
```

I'm trying to show related Stocks records on product detail page.

When I visit product detail page I get this error."Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains"
domain.com:8000/urunler/16 (for example)

I need to correct ProductDetailView class and get_context_data function but how :)

Any help?

Comment: Your code does not match your error. Your code has `title__icontains` but your error has `title_icontains`, with one underscore.

Comment: sorry updated it now

Comment: Try this: `Stocks.objects.filter(title__title__icontains=product_name).order_by('price')`

Comment: @Tech to avoid confusion in the future you should copy&paste the exact error you get, not type it. And if possible add the full stack trace.

Comment: Thnx for your help guys. I'll listen your suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've called your fields strange names, which is confusing you. `title` is not a title, but a ForeignKey to the Product model, which itself has a `title` attribute.

This would work:

```
data = Stocks.objects.filter(title__title__icontains=product_name).order_by('price')
```

but really you should rename that field to something sensible, eg `product`, so that you would do `product__title__icontains`.

Comment: I'm agree with Roseman, you should rename your `title` attribute for the Product Model.

Comment: Thnx a lot. Yes I understand that thing now and will rename it